# Where to place the MenuStrip and its items?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm used to hard code the control components of Windows.Forms; the `MenuStrip` for example. But I'm not sure about the correct location of these definitions: Is it safe to put it in a method or does it have to be in the top level of the class definition? I've tried both and both compile and run as expected. But the first choice (defining within a method) makes the menu items local to the method and —though I add the controls in that method— I'm afraid of memory issues.

See the code below:

```
namespace test
{
    class FormTest : Form
    {
        // if placed in the top level of the class —as below— it works fine.
        // MenuStrip menuMain = new MenuStrip();
        // ToolStripMenuItem exit = new ToolStripMenuItem();

        public FormTest()
        {
            this.FormTest_MenuStrip_Setup();
        }

        private void FormTest_MenuStrip_Setup()
        {
            // if placed in a method —like below— it works fine either.
            MenuStrip menuMain = new MenuStrip();
            ToolStripMenuItem exit = new ToolStripMenuItem();

            exit.Text = "Exit";
            exit.Click += FormMain_Exit_Click;
            menuMain.Items.Add(exit);
            this.Controls.Add(menuMain);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally developers do that stuff using the WinForms designer, which puts declarations of all menu items (and any other controls that you place on the Form) as class-level members in the `FormTest.designer.cs` (or whatever name your Form has) and initializes them in `InitializeComponent()` method. You just have to make sure that your constructor(s) call `InitializeComponent()` before doing anything else.

This particular arrangement is not necessary and you can define your own method for creating menu or other controls, if you do not want to use the designer. Just make sure you call this method in your constructor. Also note that declaring these controls / menuitems inside a method is not a problem because once you call `this.Controls.Add(YourControl)`, a reference to that object has already been saved, therefore GC will not erase this object even the object goes out of scope after the method finishes.

I'd rather recommend against reinventing this wheel. Unless you have good reasons to manually code your form's layout, the designer does a particularly good job here.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is very revealing.